# c++ simple function to add numbers

Tags: c++, function

first of all, I just want to say I'm newbie in c++, and I'm tring to solve a problem that I have, but no luck so far. The code is:

```
const int MAX = 100;

void funkcija(int niz[], int n, int& poc, int& sko)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        niz[i] = poc + sko;
    }
}

int main()
{
int niz[MAX];
int start, jump;

cout <<"Start element: ";
cin >> start;

cout <<"Jump element: ";
cin >> jump;

funkcija(niz, MAX, start, jump);

cout << "Ispis pocevsi od " << start << " sa skokom od " << jump << " jest: " << niz[1]<< endl;
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

What the program is supposed to do is: It asks me for start number. Lets say I pick `15`. Then it asks for jump number. I select 11. The print should go "15, 26, 37, 48, 59, 70, 81, 92." (15+11 = 26, 26+11 = 37...) and it should print all numbers until 100, which is my MAX. If I change the MAX to 1000 it should print all numbers until 1000.

Comment: You should probably add the homework tag... What have you tried so far in `funkcija()`? Show what you have so far and someone can help you figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You always set the same value in your table elements : `poc + sko`.

You want to put `poc` in `niz[0]` then

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    nit[i] = niz[i-1] + sko;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `for` loop. Loop isn't updating the next number in the sequence.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    niz[i] = poc ;
    poc += sko; // This should be added.
}
```

Also, the condition is wrong. It should be `poc < n`. Why do you need to pass `n`, when you have `MAX` as the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    niz[i] = poc + sko;
}
```

You say you want "15+11 = 26, 26+11 = 37...".

Can you think of why this isn't doing that?

For output, you only are outputting a single element from your array (the second element):

`<< niz[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you want 100 numbers, the code should look like this:

```
void funkcija(int niz[], int n, int poc, int sko)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        niz[i] = poc;
        poc = poc + sko;
    } 
}
```

Note that I removed the ampersands (`&`) from your parameters.  Adding these makes them reference parameters, which means after the function returns, the values of `start` and `jump` in your main() function are also changed.

Answer (score 0):

Has it occurred to anybody that the third expression in the `for` loop does *not* necessarily have to be `i++`? That particular expression increments `i` by 1. If you wanted to increment it by some other quantity (e.g., the "jump elemement"), what expression could you use?